NOT WORKING: Using IFS Formula when reference cell is a result of a vlookup to pivot table. Only returns N/A
I am trying to use the IFS() formula where the reference cell is the result of a VLOOKUP() (the VLOOKUP() is looking at a Pivot Table.)
It is not working, even when I've tried using (value(cell))
Below is the formula I'm using in cell Z3. Picture of the spreadsheet 
=IFS(U3="0","Missing",U3="1","All Good",U3="2","Duplicate")

AH3:AJ760 is a pivot table.
I've tried putting (value(U3)...
Please help!

Numbers shouldn't be within quotes/speechmarks --> "" . Try : =IFS(U3=0,"Missing",U3=1,"All Good",U3=2,"Duplicate") see the VLOOKUP() has returned a number, and in excel numbers are always right aligned by default while texts are left aligned unless you have changed the formatting. If you want use the numbers as text which is not suggestive then =IFS(U3&""="0","Missing",U3&""="1","All Good",U3&""="2","Duplicate") join U3 with an empty string!

Just be careful if the result returned by the vlookup is a number that that was calculated, because there may be a rounding error that will make your formula return FALSE. On another tanget, if you want to stretch your excel skills consider using the SWITCH() formula for your case.

I agree with Mayukh Bhattacharya. Numbers in formula do not need quotes. Please show us the value in U3.

Removing the quotations worked!
@gns100 I am interested in how to use Switch, though!
Thanks, everyone!
